# Objective-C: Self-variable understanding Issues

Tags: objective-c, self

I want to know some features about `self`.

1. Which context have `self` variable in class method?
2. Why `self.self` allowed in `init` method?

First:

We have a class `ExampleClass`

```
@interface ExampleClass:NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* a;

+(ExampleClass*)createExampleClass;

@end

@implementation ExampleClass

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        [self.self init]; #Allowed
        [self init]; #Not Allowed ?
    }

}

+(ExampleClass*)createExampleClass{
    /*do work here*/
    NSLog(@"Self: %@ \n Class: %@",self,[self class]);
}
@end
```

In this example we will see something like this:

```
Self: ExampleClass
Class: ExampleClass
```

But why?!

And in `init` method `[self.self init]` allowed, but not allowed '[self init]'.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a class method, `self` is the class. For classes `[self class]` simply returns `self`, so `self` and `[self class]` are basically the same thing there.

Calling `[self init]` in the `init` method doesn't make any sense, it would cause an infinite recursion. However, the compiler error you get is a restriction of ARC, if you'd use `self = [self init]`, the error would go away, but it would still make no sense. You might do this in a different initializer method though, to call the designated initializer.

Answer (score 0):

1. `self` in class method is the class object itself.
2. `NSObject` has `self` method which returns itself.

   See here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/self

   Self: ExampleClass       // Name of the class.
   Class: ExampleClass      // Name of the meta-class object which is same with class object.

If you print pointer address, you will see two objects are different.

Here's nice illustration and description.
http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

`self.self` is short for `[self self]` which does nothing but return `self`.

Answer (score -1):

`self.self.self.self.self.self` is also valid :) or [[self self].self self].self.self

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: self.self.self.self.self.self is also valid :) or [[self self].self self].self.self like that?

Comment: Below their post, not yours.